# Floating boxes in bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make floating boxes on page, so I'm curious if is possible to create this element structure in bootstrap 3?
[image: Floating boxes elements]
I can just make layout that looks like this and look at space between first and second row...
[image: I can do just this]

Comment: Just make 2 columns next to each other and put the boxes in there?

Comment: It should be time ordered items and if I change size of window under size of "small device" it'll problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) javascript library.